# Exclude a substring after a pattern is matched using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to write a regex that splits a string such as only few elements are selected. For example:
`M:\Shares\Profiles\Server\Profiles\abcd.contoso.V2.01`

the result I am aiming for is:

`abcd.V2.01`, so that the domain name i.e. `'contoso'` is dropped

However, I am unable to exclude a part of the string after a match is found. I tried

```
$original = 'M:\Shares\Profiles\Server\Profiles\abcd.contoso.V2.01'
$modified = $original -replace '.*\\([^\\.]+.contoso.V2)[^\\]*$', '$1'
```

that returns
`$modified` as `'abcd.contoso.V2'`

Comment: if the thing you want to replace is a constant, then this >>> `'M:\Shares\Profiles\Server\Profiles\abcd.contoso.V2.01'.Split('\')[-1] -replace '\.contoso'` <<< seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two capturing groups:

```
$original = 'M:\Shares\Profiles\Server\Profiles\abcd.contoso.V2.01'
$original -replace '.*\\([^\\.]*)\.contoso(\.V2[^\\]*)$', '$1$2'
# => abcd.V2.01
```

Do not forget to escape literal dots in the regex pattern. Here is a [demo of the above regex](https://regex101.com/r/23gQHe/1). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than LF chars
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `([^\\.]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any zero or more chars other than `\` and `.`
- `\.contoso` - a `.contoso` string
- `(\.V2[^\\]*)` - Group 2 (`$2`): `.V2` string and then any zero or more chars other than `\`
- `$` - end of string.